# Can I customise the value components in a case class?

Tags: scala, constructor, case-class

Say I have some case class in a library:

```
case class MyClass(a: Int, b: Int)
```

Later it turns out that there's a bug in my library and I need to apply some extra logic to one of these parameters to keep things working, so that from the user's perspective instances this can happen:

```
val x = MyClass(1, 2)
println(x.a)  // prints '3' or whatever I happen to compute for 'a'
```

In other words, the final value for `x.a` is not necessarily what was passed in to the constructor. I know this looks crazy, but trust me, I need it. `x.a` will still return whatever was passed to the constructor in most cases, but there is one value for the constructor parameter that will lead to bugs and I need to transform it.

I see two ways to achieve this. I can make `a` a `var`:

```
case class MyClass(var a: Int, b: Int) {
  a = someComputation()
}
```

but then the class becomes mutable because `a` can be set from the outside. My problem would be solved if I could remove or 'hide' the generated setter but it doesn't seem to be possible. If I add

```
private def a_=(newA: Int) {}
```

it doesn't override the setter generated by the `var` so it sees two method definitions and doesn't compile.

The second option is to create a field/method separate from the constructor parameter:

```
case class MyClass(private val _a: Int, b: Int) {
  val a = someComputation(a)
}
```

but `_a` is used in all the special generated methods such as `equals`, `toString`, etc, whereas the custom field `a` doesn't feature.

Is there any way to transform the constructor parameters without affecting the rest of the API?

Answer (score 2):

What I'd do, is override the `apply` method on the companion object to create an instance of `MyClass` with the right computation.

```
object MyClass {
   def apply(a: Int, b: Int) = new MyClass(someComputation(a),b))
}
```

Then you can call it like `val x = MyClass(1, 2)`, but you won't be able to call it like `val x = new MyClass(1, 2)` if you still want the computation to occur.

#### Apparently all of the above do not work outside the REPL.

Instead I'd settle on another method on the companion object, it's not as nice a solution, but it should work:

```
object MyClass {
   def create(a: Int, b: Int) = new MyClass(someComputation(a),b))
}
```

Comment: You can make the constructor of `MyClass` private to prohibit creating it with `new`: `case class MyClass private (a: Int, b: Int)`

Comment: Also a great idea!

Comment: This is a good idea and I got excited but when I tried it it didn't compile. The custom `apply` conflicts with the generated one.

Comment: Really? I tried it in the REPL just now and it worked fine. That's weird, maybe try `override def` instead?

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz that's an oddity of the REPL. The error appears when compiling a regular .scala file. You can see the error in the REPL if you wrap your definitions inside some other object so that they both get executed at once. Also override doesn't work because there's no inheritance involved.

Comment: Ah that sucks, sorry about that , thought it'd work if it works in the REPL. Best would probably be, to make the constructor private and use another method on the companion object. I'll make an edit.

Comment: But then `apply` won't have the right behaviour and that's not acceptable.

Answer (score -2):

So, you want something like `MyClass(a=1).a == 2` to return true? 
Do you really need an explanation why it is a bad idea? ;)

Thank god, it is not possible!

Comment: Yup. I have a test basically asserting that. Things will break if `a` remains as 1. I know it's weird but something was done wrong in the past and now that needs to be fixed without breaking backward compatibility. It's a messy situation.

Comment: Well, my question is, if you are willing to live with _this_, why in the world do you have a problem with a mutable class member? Is it, like, a competition?

Comment: It's not a disaster to use a var and I've settled for that as a compromise for now, but there was no harm in trying to fix all problems. Also I'm exploring the limits of Scala and how to do things.

Comment: @AlexHall this is not "exploring limits of scala", this is trying to write perl code in scala syntax. And yes, it _is_ a "disaster" to use a (public) var in scala, as it goes against the concept and spirit of the language.

Comment: Then Scala shouldn't make it impossible to have a var in a case class that can only be modified from within.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108334/discussion-between-alex-hall-and-dima).